# How to Mute WebView control (disable sounds)?

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I try to find how to mute WebView control in my UWP application.

The App contains WebView control to show advertisements. When user disables app sounds it is not good to play any sounds.  But some ads have sound and users are unhappy.

I've tried set ElementSoundPlayer.State as ElementSoundPlayerState.Off but it does not help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can give a code?

Comment: the code is simple. Just need to mute webview sounds **XAML**: `<WebView x:Name="_View" />`

**CS**: `_View.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9orePtm6go"));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, there is no such api for muting WebView Control . For your scenario, you could inject JavaScript that could mute sounds by using [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/web-view#create-a-web-view). Please could refer to the following code.

```
private async void PassDataBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        string mutefunctionString = @"
    var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video'),
    audios = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
    [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) { video.muted = true; });
    [].forEach.call(audios, function(audio) { audio.muted = true; }); ";

    await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { mutefunctionString });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now we can mute/unmute by calling their API directly via:

```
webView.CoreWebView2.IsMuted=true;
```

This will mute the browser webview.